# Struggling to render visualisation in PyCharm - anyone out there who can assist?

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, roc, auc

having done a classification algo, comparing NB and RF models on their abilities to classify data, I'd also like to evaluate, e.g. applying a ROCAUC plot. But several attempts appear in vain. I may be missing a tiny bit, but unfortunately I cannot spot that small change with the big impact...;o/ - anyone out there who can help? View code below. Generally, I think my question is also focusing on understanding how I can render visualisations generated as part of a def command. Tried 'return figure', 'plt.show' - nothing visualised...

```
# ROCAUC curve - Naive Bayes
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, precision_score, accuracy_score, recall_score, f1_score
from scipy import interp
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def ROCcurves(y_test, pred2):
    n_classes = 2
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test, pred2)
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    fpr['micro'], tpr['micro'], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), pred2.ravel())
    all_fpr = np.nunique(np.concatenate(fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)))

    mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
    for i in range(n_classes):
        mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

    mean_tpr /= n_classes

    fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
    tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr

    # plot figure (micro and macro)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], label='micro-average-ROC-curve (area = {0:0.2f})'.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
         linewidth=2)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"], label='macro-average-ROC-curve (area = {0:0.2f})'.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
             linewidth=2)

    for i in range(n_classes):
        plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label="ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})"

                                       ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
    plt.xlim([0.0], [1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0], [1.05])
    plt.xlabel("False positive rate")
    plt.ylabel("True positive rate")
    plt.title("ROC to multi-class")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you call the function? For example, I'd expect a line at the end of all this that looks something like `ROCcurves(y, p)`, not indented so it's not part of the `def`.  This, btw, is not a "def command" but a function definition, which I point out because the terminology mistake is consistent with never calling the function and expecting it to run.

Comment: Thx, tom10. While still kind of newbie to the entire Python universe, I need you to elaborate a bit on your explanation. I'd view the function definition as a way to generate my ROCAUC graph, expecting the plt,show() to throw the graph visually. Is there a chance you could show in an updated code how to make the call? - BR, Hubsandspokes

Comment: That's difficult to do given your example. What would I pass in for `y_test` and `pred2`? But... overall, I think you need to approach this differently. Ideally, before you post here, you'd have figured out a line or two of a program that's not working, and then post a minimal working example that we could run (of about 10 lines, + or -), that illustrates that. Your current approach, of 50 lines of code that don't work and asking people what's wrong, is not an effective way to write code. Instead, write a few lines at a time, test, and go forward. Then you'll know where the problems are.